# Solving graphically equation

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve a equation graphically but the plot doesn't display anything...

```
eqn = K == (Cc + x)/((Ca - 2 x)^2 (Cb - x))
const = {K -> 0.016, Ca -> 42, Cb -> 28, Cc -> 4}
f[x_] = eqn /. const
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 20}]
```

I tried with Plot, but it doesn't work, how can I solve it graphically?

Comment: `f = eqn /. const` and `Plot[f, {x, 0, 20}]`, or leave `f[x_]` as is and use  `Plot[Evaluate[f[x]], {x, 0, 20}]`.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform and that's all I have to do to solve it graphycally? Or there are others steps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
eqn = K == (Cc + x)/((Ca - 2 x)^2 (Cb - x));
const = {K -> 0.016 // Rationalize, Ca -> 42, Cb -> 28, Cc -> 4};
f[x_] = eqn /. const;

plt = Plot[Evaluate@f[x], {x, 0, 20}, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]

Finding the x-value of the point on the plot line that is closest to `y == 0`

```
SortBy[Cases[plt, Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity][[1]], Abs[#[[2]]] &][[1, 1]]

(* 15.9261 *)
```

Compare with the actual root

```
Solve[f[x], x, Reals][[1]] // N

(* {x -> 15.923} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is another approach in which is plotted the crossing-point with `MeshFunction`, and extract that point:

```
eqn = K == (Cc + x)/((Ca - 2 x)^2 (Cb - x));
const = {K -> 0.016 // Rationalize, Ca -> 42, Cb -> 28, Cc -> 4};
f[x_] = eqn /. const
```

$$\frac{2}{125}=\frac{x+4}{(42-2 x)^2 (28-x)}$$

```
plt = Plot[Evaluate@f[x], {x, 0, 20}, MaxRecursion -> 5, Mesh -> {{0.}}, 
MeshFunctions -> Function[{x}, -(2/125) + (4 + x)/((42 - 2 x)^2 (28 - x))], 
Frame -> True, 
MeshStyle -> {{Red, PointSize[Medium]}, {Green, PointSize[Medium]}}]
```

[image]

```
Cases[plt[[1, 1, 1]], {a_, b_} /; Abs[b] < 10^-6]
```

> {{15.923, -1.13533*10^-7}}